# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in AffinitiesController#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, localhost

When I try to access `http://localhost:3000/affinities`, I get the error in the title. Below it reads 'Couldn't find Affinity without an ID'.

Here is my 'affinities_controller.rb':

```
class AffinitiesController < InheritedResources::Base
def index
    @affinities = Affinity.all
end

def new
    @affinity = Affinity.new
end

def create
    @affinity = Affinity.new(params[:affinity])

    if @affinity.save
        redirect_to @affinity
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def show
    @affinity = Affinity.find(params[:id])
end

def edit
    @affinity = Affinity.find(params[:id])
end

def update
@affinity = Affinity.find(params[:id])

debugger
    @affinity.update_attributes(params[:affinities])
    @affinity.save
    redirect_to @affinity
end

def destroy
    @affinity = Affinity.find(params[:id])
    @affinity.destroy

    redirect_to affinity_index_path
end
```

The error is caused by the index method. Here is the view for index:

```
%h3 Affinities
=link_to 'New Affinity', new_affinity_path
<br><br>

%h3 Listing Affinities
%table
    - @affinities.each do |affinity|
        %tr
            %td=affinity.profile_affinity
            %td=affinity.tip_affinity
            %td=link_to 'Show', affinity_path(affinity)
            %td=link_to 'Edit', edit_affinity_path(affinity)
            %td=link_to 'Delete', affinity_path(affinity), :method => :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }
```

And here are my routes:

```
Sxs::Application.routes.draw do
resources :prediction_configs

resources :affinities

#----------------------------------------------------------------#
...
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: I think the error is caused by the `show` method, you should check `params[:id]`. if `params[:id]` is blank, `find` method will raise `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception.

Comment: Can you post the error stack?

Comment: What is the error stack exactly? I'm new to ruby.

Comment: Actually, I removed the show method and I got the same error:
`ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in AffinitiesController#index`

Comment: The error stack is the list of errors that shows up in the terminal on the server that you are running.  Do you actually have any affinities in the database?  Try adding one and see if you still have the error.

Comment: I was thinking that might be it. How can I add an affinity to the database? I'm using pgAdmin III with PostgreSQL.

Comment: Also, this was my error: 
`ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Affinity without an ID):
  app/views/users/sessions/_new.html.haml:21:in _app_views_users_sessions__new_
html_haml__572186013_66722136'
  app/views/layouts/application.html.haml:124:in _app_views_layouts_application
_html_haml___1055339256_61642452'`

Comment: post you Affinitiy Model, your rails version, stack trace, and edit it in the above question. Since your error appears to be in users/sessions/_new.html.haml, have you used some sort of authentication mechanism? Post this file also. Also your controller extends from `InheritedResources::Base`. Try extending it from ApplicationController